# Not enough prayer

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla

Once, I heard the following sentence: "If something did not happened yet, it is because you didn't pray or because you didn't pray enough." Is this correct? Who said this sentence?

Comment: I think it based on the idea in וָאֶתְחַנַּ֖ן that if Moshe had prayed just one more time to go to Eretz Yisrael, he would have, so Hashem had to tell him "enough". See Devarim Rabbah 11:10

Comment: This site includes the line:  As Reb Nosson [Nathan of Breslov?] would say, “Whenever there is a lack, it is either because the person didn’t pray…or didn’t pray enough!”   https://www.breslov.org/author/yehudisgolshevsky/page/18/?print=print-page

Comment: Sounds absolutely outrageous. Why did all these great tzaddikim die? They should all still be alive and healthy, and everyone else too!

Comment: And why has Moshiach not come?

Comment: @MichoelR Great question

Comment: @shmosel I'm not sure if it's a great question, or just a demonstration that I have no real idea what they're talking about. It seems very strange.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I think the way _your_ quote sounds is much more understandable to me. Now we just need to define what a "lack" is. I don't think it means, Whatever I feel like asking for.

Comment: @RabbiKaii That sounds like the source, but does it not say the opposite of the claim? It sounds like you are not _supposed_ to pray for things that Hashem does not want. Of course! Especially because the Midrash says a different idea: If Moshe had kept praying, people would have drawn a negative impression, "The servant stubbornly keeps asking and the master stubbornly keeps refusing."

Comment: @MichoelR so the phrase should be amended with ", or because one's not allowed to pray for _that_"